# Write JDBC query results to CSV file?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to setup a test plan to execute a query and write the results to a csv file.

Following the advice from this question:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26456/write-jdbc-request-results-to-csv-file

I have setup my test plan. It runs without issue, but a `foo.csv` file is not created.

this is the code in the JSR223 preprocessor:

```
resultSet = vars.getObject("resultSet");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (Object row : resultSet ) {
    iter = row.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        pair = iter.next();
        result.append(pair.getValue());
        result.append(",");
    }
    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("foo.csv"), result.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: @Mureinik updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is being written in current working directory, you can locate where JMeter written it by running the following command in the [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) application:

```
find / -type f -name 'foo.csv'
```

You can also amend the last line of code in order to explicitly specify full path to the CSV file like:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("/Users/aoppenheim/Desktop/foo.csv"), result.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Also I would suggest switching "Language" to `groovy` as `java` assumes using Beanshell interpreter and it might become a performance bottleneck in case of high loads. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually working, the csv file was just not being written where I expected. I added this to find the file:

```
log.info(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```